# Multiple parent in RadTreeView

Tags: asp.net, telerik, treeview

Is it possible in RadTreeView that having a multiple parent and in that multiple parent have a child?

maybe can be described like this:

```
Node 1
-Member of Node 1 - 1
    Node 2
    - Member of Node 2 - 1
    - Member of Node 2 - 2
    - Member of Node 2 - 3
        Node 3
        - Member of Node 3 - 1
```

or if it is not possible to use RadTreeView, is there any control that can provide things like this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

RadTreeView supports multiple levels of nesting nodes in the very same treeview, this depends on your data source. You can find an example with several levels here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/populatingwithdata/entitydatasource/defaultcs.aspx

Or, you can use the ItemTemplate of the node to put arbitrary controls there, see here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx